# Removing warnings/messages on power point presentation with Rmarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, powerpoint

I am new to Rmarkdown and I am trying to build a powerpoint presentation from an external R script in R markdown.

My initial R script looks like that

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(grid)

Biomass_S1<-data.frame(col1=c(2001:2020), col2 = runif(20), col3 = runif(20))
Biomass_S2<-data.frame(col1=c(2001:2020), col2 = rnorm(20), col3 = rnorm(20)) 
Biomass_S3<-data.frame(col1=c(2001:2020), col2 = rnorm(20), col3 = rnorm(20)) 
Biomass_S4<-data.frame(col1=c(2001:2020), col2 = rnorm(20), col3 = rnorm(20))
All_Biomass<-list(Biomass_S1, Biomass_S2, Biomass_S3, Biomass_S4)


# Plot each group from each dataframe in a loop
one_dataframe<-bind_rows(All_Biomass, .id="df") # create on single dataframe to work with
plot_list = list() # create empty list to put plots in
y_cols<-setdiff(names(one_dataframe), c("df","Year")) # set columns to use as y-values (as a character vector)
couleurs<-c("1"="#fde725","2"="#35b779","3"="#31688e","4"="#440154")
labels<-c("Scenario 1 ", "Scenario 2 ",
          "Scenario 3 ", "Scenario 4 ")
# loop over the columns and assign the plots to the list
for(col in y_cols){
  plot_list[[col]]=
    ggplot(data=one_dataframe, aes(x=Year, y=.data[[col]], col= df))+
    scale_color_manual(name="Scenarios", values=c(couleurs), labels=c(labels))+
    geom_line(size=0.2)+
    geom_smooth(method="loess",fill="white", alpha=0,data=one_dataframe[one_dataframe$Year>=2020,])+
    labs(title=col)+
    geom_vline(xintercept = 2020, linetype="dashed")+
    theme_classic()+
    guides(colour=guide_legend(nrow=2))+
    theme(legend.title = element_text(face="bold"),
          title = element_text(face="bold"),
          plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5),
          legend.position = c("top"),
          legend.key.width = unit(1, "cm"),
          legend.text = element_text(size=12),
          text = element_text(size=14, family ="serif"))
}
```

I end up with several of these kind of graph, which is what I need. [image]

On R markdown, I am trying to plot some specific graphs that I just created, but I keep having warnings/messages showing up on Power point.

My code chunk in R markdown is the following:

````
    ```{r, echo = FALSE, error=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.keep='all'}
# Run an external R script
source("C:/Users/xxxx/GitHub/Repositories/xxx-model/scripts/test.R")

graphs_to_plot<- plot_list[c("TKW","SRKW","NRKW")]

for (i in 1:length(graphs_to_plot)) {
  plot(graphs_to_plot[[i]])
}

```
````

But the resulting power point plots look like that

[image]

How can I get rid of the messages/warnings on the left of the graphs??
I looked at previous posts and tried everything I could find (message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, error=FALSE, fig.keep='all'..., either together or separate and nothing seem to work). Also, when I use message=FALSE, every graph (but the first one) disappear from my presentation...

Thank you for help !

Comment: Try adding “quietly = TRUE” to the library calls.  It looks like the warnings are being captured when dplyr is being loaded.

Comment: `message = FALSE` isn't in your code chunk although you say you tried it. But I think that's what you want.